# CSRF token missing or incorrect from form on `/`

Tags: jquery, python, django, csrf

I have this in `urls.py`:

```
url("^$", direct_to_template, {"template": "index.html"}, name="home"),
url("^searched-location", views.searched_location, name="searched_location"),
```

I have this in `index.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load pages_tags mezzanine_tags i18n staticfiles %}

{% block main %}
<form id="my-form class="input-group">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <script src="{% static "script/script.js" %}"></script>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

`script.js` has this line:

```
document.getElementById("my-form").addEventListener("submit",function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
},false);

function when_User_Types_Something_Send_That_Stuff_To_The_Backend(typedStuff){
    // some code
    $.post("/searched-location",{typed_stuff: stuff_the_user_typed});
}
```

`views.py` has this:

```
def searched_location(request):
    print request
    # More code here
```

Problem is I'm getting this error in my terminal when I run `python manage.py runserver` locally:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /searched-location
[11/Jan/2018 01:57:06] "POST /searched-location HTTP/1.1" 403 2502
```

Why is the CSRF token missing or incorrect? How do I find or correct it?

Comment: `$.post("/searched-location",{typed_stuff: stuff_the_user_typed});` does not contain the csrf token.

Comment: I don't see the connection between your form and the code that posts to searched-location.

Comment: The docs show how to do this specifically with jQuery: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/

Answer (score 0):

You're not including the CSRF token in your POST request.

Change your code to something like:

```
$.post("/searched-location",{typed_stuff: stuff_the_user_typed, csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()});
```

to include it in your request.